# Login to Facebook button without requesting user permission

Tags: facebook

I want to add a "Login to Facebook" button to my page. However, I don't want to have the user prompted to grant my app access. I don't need any of the user's personal info so they shouldn't need to grant me access. Is this possible?

Comment: You can set required permissions in `scope` parameter, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

> I don't need any of the user's personal info

So why to use the facebook API?

You must be fetching at least the `ID` of the user right? That's the part of just the basic information; so in the least case the user will be prompted to grant the permission to your app to fetch the basic info. You shouldn't bother much, since most of the users don't hesitate sharing just their basic information.

Comment: How could I do this without the Facebook API?

Comment: Prompt the user to login to their Facebook account.

Comment: I m asking you that- WHY do want to do so? WHY login from faebook? What data do you want to fetch of the user from facebook? That's what I asked you earlier too.